# Serviio output mp4

Tags: video

I'm using a serviio server to stream my videos,
I have my custom profile witch dilivers my videos:

```
<Profile id="videoDrive" name="VIDEODRIVE" extendsProfileId="1" alwaysEnableTranscoding="true" selectable="false">
    <Transcoding>           
        <Audio targetContainer="mp3">
            <Matches container="flac" />
            <Matches container="ogg" />
            <Matches container="lpcm" />
            <Matches container="adts" />
            <Matches container="asf" />
            <Matches container="wavpack" />
            <Matches container="mpc" />
            <Matches container="ape" />
        </Audio>
    </Transcoding>  
    <OnlineTranscoding>
        <!-- by default transcode for ios / android devices -->
        <Video targetContainer="applehttp" targetVCodec="h264" targetACodec="aac" forceStereo="true">
            <Matches container="*" />
        </Video>
    </OnlineTranscoding>
    <AlternativeQualities>
        <Quality type="MEDIUM">
            <Transcoding>
                <Video targetContainer="applehttp" targetVCodec="h264" targetACodec="aac" forceStereo="true" >
                    <Matches container="*" />
                </Video>
            </Transcoding>

        </Quality>

    </AlternativeQualities>
    <ThumbnailsResolution>HD</ThumbnailsResolution>
    <AutomaticImageRotation>true</AutomaticImageRotation>
</Profile>
```

But there is one small issue with the medium quality, when I go to the original stream it plays an mp4 stream and when I download it it downloads an mp4 file,

But when I go to the medium stream, it downloads an m3u8 file

also I use the Jplayer plugin to play my videos, and the original link is working fine, but the medium doesn't play, it gives the following error:

```
 jPlayer 2.9.2 : id='jquery_jplayer_1' : Error!
Media URL could not be loaded.
Check media URL is valid.
```

Any body got any clue on how to fix this? I would really like to offer some lower qualities for making it more accessible on mobile devices.

I tried setting it to all the possible targetContainers, but no luck on that.
I tried using the other build in profiles, but non of them provide an MEDIUM / LOW stream that works for Jplayer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is not possible:[Serviio Forum](http://forum.serviio.org/viewtopic.php?p=99291#p99291)